# Angular Date Format Not Working

Tags: angularjs

I have a Html like this.

```
<select name="paymentList" class="form-control" tabindex=""
                        ng-focus="true"
                        ng-disabled="!showRoomPaymentList"
                        move-focus-by-enter-key
                        ng-model="paymentList"
                        ng-options="s.FromDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' + ' To ' + s.ToDate|date:'dd-MM-yyyy'  for s in showRoomPaymentList track by s.PaymentDurationId"
                        ng-required="true">
                    <option value="">--Select Payment Duration--</option>
                </select>
```

Output like this:
01-06-2016 To 2016-06-30T00:00:00
But I want It like this
01-06-2016 To 30-06-2016

Second part date format not working how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pack 'subexpression with filter' in () as in `(anydate|date:'yyyy')`.

So, in your case:

```
s.FromDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' + ' To ' + s.ToDate|date:'dd-MM-yyyy'
```

change to

```
(s.FromDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy') + ' To ' + (s.ToDate|date:'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jsggspm0/

Comment: Thanks. khajaamin
Yes This work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

May be this solved your question but you have to convert your dates in controller using  format function.

Please let me know if any changes needed snippet is working.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('Test', function($scope,$filter) {

  $scope.selected = null;
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'a',
    value: 1,
    something: "xyz",
from:"2016-06-30T00:00:00",
to:"2016-06-30T00:00:00"
  }, {
    name: 'b',
    value: 2,
    something: "xyz",
from:"2016-06-30T00:00:00",
to:"2016-06-30T00:00:00"

  }, {
    name: 'c',
    value: 3,
    something: "xyz",
from:"2016-06-30T00:00:00",
to:"2016-06-30T00:00:00"

  }]


  $scope.show = function() {
    alert("selectec " + $scope.selected.name + ' with value ' + $scope.selected.value);
  }

  $scope.format = function(i) {
    return  $filter('date')(i.from, "dd/MM/yyyy") + " to "+$filter('date')(i.to, "dd/MM/yyyy");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="app">

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Test">
    <select data-ng-options="i as format(i) for i in items" ng-model="selected">
    </select>
    <button ng-click="show()">press</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```